# Как принимать данные по SPI?

Tags: c, stm32, spi

На мастере SPI пишу программу, которая должна взаимодействовать со slave: отсылать и принимать данные. С отправкой никаких проблем, а вот с приёмом есть нерешённые, слабо освещённые в литературе вопросы.

Мастер SPI передаёт байт: тактовый информационный сигнал. Слейв видит тактовый сигнал и начинает принимать этот байт. Но если у него есть данные для передачи, может ли он под этот же тактовый сигнал их передать? Примет ли их контроллер? А если slave не передаёт в этот момент данные, примет ли контроллер 0xff?

Теперь другая ситуация. Slave имеет данные, которые он подготовил к передаче в ответ на запрос мастера, и ждёт тактовый сигнал, чтобы их передать. Как тактовый сигнал появится на линии? Мастер должен передать 0xff? Ведь в мастере нет регистра, с помощью которого можно было бы выдать тактовый сигнал без передачи данных, а чтение буферного регистра лишь возвращает последний принятый байт, а не выдаёт тактовый сигнал.

Но допустим, slave начал передавать данные под тактовый сигнал мастера. Примет ли он в этот момент 0xff?

Используется контроллер 1982ВЕ92У (Миландр).

Comment: То, что вы описываете, конфигурируется параметрами фазы. Сам по себе протокол синхронный. Я рекомендую почитать спецификацию на SPI протокол(ы) (их в общем случае несколько, наверняка у вас используется вариант Motorola).

Comment: @0andriy, вы добавили метку [tag:stm32]. Пусть правка останется: это способствует обнаружению вопроса специалистами. Но вообще вопрос не относится к stm32. Контроллер Миландр.

Comment: @maesrto именно так, я добавил самое близкое, на что он похож. Насколько я понял он даже в некотором смысле аналог (конкретно ВЕ9х) какого-то контроллера из stm32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPI - штука дуплексная. Мастер и слейв определяются только тем, кто формирует тактовый сигнал, а кто под него подстраивается.

По одному и тому же тактовому сигналу устройство принимает один байт и передаёт второй. Более того, обмен по SPI в простейшем случае так и записывается:

```
unsigned char SpiTransfer (unsigned char data)
{
    регистр данных = data;
    while (идёт обмен) {}
    return регистр данных;
} 
unsigned char SpiRead ()
{
    return SpiTransfer (0xFF); // передавать можно что угодно
}
void SpiWrite (unsigned char data)
{
     SpiTransfer (data);
}
```

Соответственно, да, если нам надо читать, мы записываем произвольное значение; если надо записать, параллельно что-то считается (нули, единички или какой-то мусор - зависит от реализации второго устройства).

Comment: Пишите *дуплексная*, а пример для *полудуплекса*. Нестыковочка.

Comment: @0andriy, почему здесь полудуплекс? По-моему, код здесь как раз дуплексный, а описание ниже - полудуплексное.

Comment: *spi_transfer()* - дуплексный. Этим всё и оканчивается.

Comment: spi_transfer() - дуплексный. А мышление в большинстве случаев - полудуплексное. Простейший протокол: "отправить команду, получить ответ" - полудуплекс в чистейшем виде, и на SPI будет выглядеть как "отправить команду, выкинуть принятый мусор; отправить байт, прочитать ответ"